# No value given for One or more required parameters in visual basic 6.0 with access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to do a simple select in a access 2007 DB as:

```
sqlSelect = "select * from Datos_De_Quejas where Ape_Pax = " & textape.Text & " " 
RS.Open sqlSelect, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

The table is called `Datos_De_Quejas`, the column `Ape_Pax` and `cnn` is the connection.

I checked the spelling 100 times and it looks correct, but it gives me the following error.

> No value given for One or more required parameters

The following select is working perfectly fine in the same procedure:

```
sqlSelect = "select * from Datos_De_Quejas where ID = " & textnro.Text & " "
RS.Open sqlSelect, cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong.
Thank you!

Comment: What are the values of `textape` and `textnro`?

Comment: Did you try textnro.Value? .text property is only available to a control with focus. You do not need a property if you want .value, it is the default, so me.textnro would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that ID is an integer field, while Ape_Pax is a varchar.

try:

```
 "select * from Datos_De_Quejas where Ape_Pax = '" & textape.Text & "' "
```

with the single quotes.

Also, building an SQL statement like that -- particularly when used with text from a user input field -- is an extremely bad idea.   Use a parameterized query ( "select * from Datos_De_Quejas where Ape_Pax = ?") and pass the Text as a parameter.

Comment: In MS Access `textape.Text` will only be available if `textape` has focus, so there may well be a problem there. Furthermore, you need to be wary of text containing single quotes.